# Cancel edit before it gets approved

Tags: support, feature-request, suggested-edits

I recently edited a question on Stack Overflow and while it was waiting for an approval, the person asking the question edited the post and made my edit useless.
I was looking for a way to cancel my edit.
Is there such a way? If not, should this feature be added or is this situation too rare?

Comment: You can edit an edit (excuse me) to make it worthwhile as the original post gets edited (cough). It seems that in your case, the asker edited his question within the grace period, which let it slip without conflicting with your suggested edit.

Comment: Your suggested edit should have been automatically rejected I think. Wasn't it?

Comment: @Bart It's made within the grace period.

Comment: Link @Unihedro?

Comment: It'd be helpful to be able to cancel/retract a suggested edit. I inadvertenly suggested an edit to a question when I meant to edit my own answer.

Comment: I just realised that the lack of a way to retract a suggested edit is rather annoying. I just made a suggested edit in a question, after finding a long noun phrase that I initially parsed as singular followed by "have". I changed that to "has" and submitted the form. About two seconds later, I realised that the NP was actually plural, and tried to change back to "have". The software didn't let me (complaining that I hadn't changed anything). I found no way to retract my suggested edit. Now, almost an hour later, my suggested edit is still in the review queue (and I just hope it gets declined).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to "cancel" a suggested edit that you've already submitted.

However, you should find that if the author made an edit to a post (or anybody with instant editing powers for that matter), your suggested edit will be rejected.

This will show up as rejected by "Community♦". These rejections do **not** count against you, so don't be alarmed when they show up (and they show up fairly often).

Comment: "These rejections do not count against you" - What does that mean? In my suggested edits "Editor Stats", Community♦ rejected edits increment my number of rejected edits.

Comment: @Unihedro: They will not cause you to be edit-banned.

Comment: Why not provide a cancel button? Or time will be wasted.

Comment: I agree with @jw_, there should be a cancel button.

Comment: 2023 here and still NO `cancel` option. annoying.

Comment: I have just tried to fix the code block of a question, by adding simple backticks and there were backslashes in the xml that did not appear in the question as you see it. I wanted to go back and undo my changes, but it was not possible, so I left a long note trying to explain.