# Canceling an obsolete edit

Tags: support, edits

In this question, the OP asks about cancelling an edit that is obsoleted by an edit of the *poster* of a question:
[Cancel edit before it gets approved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280891/cancel-edit-before-it-gets-approved)

In [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9229333), it seems like another edit was made in parallel by *someone else*. It only showed up after I've done mine, and now it looks like my edit was simply reverting most of that edit. Of course, my edit is now obsolete and I want to retract it since the other one was even better. Is that possible?

(The reason why I'm asking is that I don't want that edit to show up on my rejected edit list for vanity reasons ;-) )

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmm I wonder what would happen if you copied the title and body from [the other user's edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32119056/edit/9c01c290-0fba-44bc-9328-e0c02cf2c67d) and pasted it into yours. I don't recall if that would actually cancel the edit... or be treated as a no-op or something.

Comment: @BoltClock From an experiment I did a while ago to test something else, if you edit to match the current body of the post, it won't let you submit your re-edit of the suggested edit. The edit will still be reviewed. (This might be different if another edit was suggested and you edit to match _that_ but I assume not.)

Comment: So... no way of noping your own edit once you regret it.

Comment: @BoltClock Right, just tried it: "Nothing has changed."

Comment: On the plus side, it looks like your edit only needs one more reject vote and it's out of the queue. Won't hurt you as long as you don't have a lot of edit suggestions rejected here recently. Only your vanity will be hurt. ;)

Comment: The situation changed a bit. I made another edit to make the main point of the question clear from the beginning, and that cancels out my previous problem. However, the two rejections are still there. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Editing before your suggested edit is cleared just edits your suggestion and doesn't submit a new edit. The previous votes in the queue remain, but all reviewers who get the post _after_ you've edited your suggestion will see the new suggestion. So yeah, it's expected behavior.