# Cancel Edit Request and Write New Question

Tags: discussion

I recently made a suggested edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/967916/9559310) which after further thought, I believe needs to be rejected.  I was hoping to cancel it, since it hasn't been reviewed, but I discovered [that's not possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280998/9559310).  Initially, the reason that I made my edit was because all of the answers gave outdated information, and the note I added should be correct in the context of those answers.  However, after submitting the edit, I realized that the linked post doesn't really do much to answer the specific question that I edited.

So now my thought is that it would be better to create a new question asking essentially the same thing - it is a problem I am trying to solve myself right now, after all - and link the old question with outdated answers.

I believe I've already messed up once with adding that edit, so I wanted to double check with the community to ask if this is the correct approach for me to take.  My specific concern is whether or not I would be in danger of the question being a duplicate, even though the existing question with answers is outdated.