# How can I escape Suggested Edit purgatory?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I have [a bot account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15573995/broomba) which I would like to bring up to 100 rep so that it can be made a room owner in chat.

I was making good progress just by making simple grammar fixes to posts with common typos, but in chat, I got several suggestions to propose tag wiki edits instead.

So I did that; but this seems to have been a mistake. The account has been stuck on +93 rep for over a week now, whereas previously, I was able to get at least a few accepted edit suggestions per day.

I can no longer propose any new edits, because the proposed edit queue is capped at five pending suggested edits.

My concrete and immediate question is: **How can I get out of this situation?**

More tangentially, are there useful feature requests which would help alleviate this problem?  I found [Cancel edit before it gets approved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280891/cancel-edit-before-it-gets-approved) and some related proposals, but they have all been met with "not currently possible" and/or very limited support.

In the same vein, perhaps it would make sense if there was an expiry date for unreviewed edit proposals. Maybe they could be reassigned to the Community user after, say, a month, so as to allow the account to propose new edits again?

Also, secondarily, are there rate limiting mechanisms I should be aware of? I notice that tag wiki proposals require a higher level of privilege from reviewers, so maybe the problem is just that these proposed edits have not received any reviews because of that. It would be vaguely useful if I could see how many reviews a proposed edit has received (and perhaps also how many reveiewers have opted to skip reviewing it) but there doesn't seem to be any tooling for that?

Comment: "How can I get out of this situation?" Post on Meta and hope some 20k+ users are sympathetic enough to review your bot account's pending edits. Have you already tried... wait.

Comment: There are two problems: 1) less people are qualifies to review tag wiki edit and tag wiki edits require more work to review 2) the tag wikis you propose are borderline. The anakonda3 wiki, for example, has a generic text about anakonda but nothing what the 3 means and when it should be used. This also makes it more likely that reviewers skip.

Comment: Why not just post a half-baked, useless answer to a Java/Python/Regex question? You can get more rep like that.

Comment: You can approve tag edits at 5k: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits

Comment: @oguzismail lol, you sure you are not British?  :)

Comment: We have sarcasm in the good old USA, too, @MartinJames. And I'm sure they have it in Turkey, too.

Comment: come on, you of all people must know tag wiki edits get forever to approve! And since the needs of wiki editors and reviewers are constantly ignored, that's what we get in the end - long wait times. I've reviewed a couple I could find, hope this helps

Comment: Mission accomplished, it would appear...

Comment: Immediate problem solved, yes (thanks everyone who pitched in) but I'd still like to see a discussion of how to solve this in the general case, without requiring a meta intervention.

Comment: So, what's the *broomba* going to do? Sounds like a version of the Roomba with a penchant for witch-hunting.

Comment: @tripleee without the substantial rework of suggested edits? Don't think anything can be done. First off, I would move all wiki and excerpt reviews to their own queue to stop sorting them randomly in the midst of comma corrections. It would've drastically sped up review times. Secondly, reduced the number of rep required to edit tag wikis/excerpts unilaterally - barring them to 0.07% is ridiculous

Comment: @Adrian Let's see what I can pull off; the plan is to help you keep track of low-value posts which are not yet ripe for Roomba.

Comment: SIde note: I think you should say in the profile of your bot that it's a bot and it belongs to you.

Comment: @Scratte Thanks; done. I was planning on doing that once the bot has some actual activity to show, but I guess it makes sense to have a brief description already just in case somebody who reviews the bot's edits would be curious about what it's up to.